# Pytest -Get one item from multiple returned values

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I've e2e_te_data.json file which includes my 2 different test points. It means I will have 2 test case data and give the pytest and it will execute 2 different test cases.

`**e2e_te_data.json**

```
[{   "dataSource":"dataSource1",  
     "machineName":"MachineName_X", 
},

{`   "dataSource":"dataSource2",  
    "machineName":"MachineName_Y",
}]
```

--`-------This is my code:

```
 def read_test_data_from_json():
     JsonFile = open('..\\e2eTestData.json','r')
     h=[]    
     convertedJsonStr=[]
     json_input = JsonFile.read()
     parsedJsonStr = json.loads(json_input)  # Parse JSON string to Python dict
     for i in range(0, len(parsedJsonStr)):
         convertedJsonStr.append(json.dumps(parsedJsonStr[i]))
         h.append(parsedJsonStr[i]['machineName']) 
     return convertedJsonStr,h



@pytest.mark.parametrize("convertedJsonStr,h", (read_test_data_from_json()[0],read_test_data_from_json()[1]))
def test_GetFrequencyOfAllToolUsage(convertedJsonStr,h):
    objAPI=HTTPMethods()
    frequencyOfToolResultFromAPIRequest=objAPI.getFrequencyOfTools(read_test_data_from_json[0])
    print(h)
```

[Value of convertedJsonstr variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG5E4.png)

I want to get one item of convertedJsonStr and h returned from read_test_data_from_json method when it comes into test_GetFrequencyOfAllToolUsage method. But I see all items of convertedJsonStr and h as image above.

Comment: "I want to get one item " - first item or last item or random item?

Comment: In `read_test_data`, you return a tuple of arrays - what you need instead, is an array of tuples as input for `parametrize`.

Comment: Also, in your test, you don't use the parameter, istead you try to read it again inside the test. I don't understand also what this parameters should be - from the json data I would have expected that you want to read `dataSource` and `machineName` - as is, it is not clear wha you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First Item

```
def read_test_data_from_json():
     JsonFile = json.load(open('..\\e2eTestData.json','r'))
     # First item
    return JsonFile[0], JsonFile[0]["machineName"]
```

## Last item

`return JsonFile[-1], JsonFile[-1]["machineName"]`

## Random item

```
item = random.choice(JsonFile)
return item, item["machineName"]
```